# xlsk is not defined though i have used it's cdn

Tags: javascript, html, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to convert xls(excel) file in json but program is giving me error xlsk is not defined though I have defined it in my script tag. I have tried changing the cdn but it's the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>

  <!-- Import TensorFlow.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Import tfjs-vis -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.min.js" integrity="sha512-Bkf3qaV86NxX+7MyZnLPWNt0ZI7/OloMlRo8z8KPIEUXssbVwB1E0bWVeCvYHjnSPwh4uuqDryUnRdcUw6FoTg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></head>

<body>
  <h1>nir</h1>
  <input type="file" class="csv" name="myfile">
  <script src="script2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script2

```
let selectedFile;
document.querySelector('.csv').addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    var file_reader= new FileReader();
    file_reader.onload=function(event){
      var data = event.target.result;

      var workbook = xlsk.read(data, {
        type:"binary"
      });
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet=>{
        let rowObject = xlsk.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(
          workbook.Sheets[sheet]
        );
        let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(rowObject);
        console.log(jsonObject);
      });
    };
    file_reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that be xlsx instead of xlsk ?

Comment: the cdn you added in code gives "invalid file type" error.

Comment: @ Anita no it does not give invalid file type

Comment: @ Raffon isn't that the same thing what you wrote??